# jQuery html method doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I'd like to know why this piece of code is not working in Chrome. It works well in Safari. I've been searching for a bit now, but I can't seem to find an answer!

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var jQuerydivsa = jQuery("div.f-sr");

  jQuery("#s-alf").on("click", function() {
    var orderDivsa = jQuerydivsa.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (jQuery(a).find("h4.b-desc").text()) > (jQuery(b).find("h4.b-desc").text());
    });
    jQuery("#brand-srt").html(orderDivsa);
  });
});
```

The HTML can be simplified as:

```
<button class="btn btn--light btn--bordered btn-md">Sort by <span class="lnr lnr-chevron-down"></span></button>
   <div class="dropdown dropdown--author">
        <ul>

           <li id="s-alf">
                <a > A-Z</a>
           </li>

        </ul>
   </div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-6  f-sr>
    <h4 class="b-desc"> A </h4>
    <h4 class="b-desc"> B </h4>
</div>
```

The last command to show the sorted divs doesn't do nothing and no error shows up in my console. I'm pretty sure that the last line in the script doesn't work, since I tried to debug it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: We need a full working example if you require help to debug a problem, however you're comparing strings using `>` which is going to use implicit coercion which is never a good idea. Try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on the values before making the comparison.

Comment: Add your markup as well please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have edited my question adding the html. I have tried with parseInt but still not working!

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your code: missing quotes, sorting wrong object, wrong return value from sorting function, and so on...

I made a working example, you may compare this working code with your, if you have questions please ask, I'll answer tomorrow.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var jQuerydivsa = jQuery("div.f-sr h4");
    
      jQuery("#s-alf").on("click", function() {
        var orderDivsa = jQuerydivsa.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (
            jQuery.trim(jQuery(a).text())
            >
            jQuery.trim(jQuery(b).text())
            ? 1 : -1);
        });
        jQuery("#brand-srt").html('').append(orderDivsa);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

    <button class="btn btn--light btn--bordered btn-md">
      Sort by
      <span class="lnr lnr-chevron-down"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown--author">
      <ul>
        <li id="s-alf">
          A-Z
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="brand-srt" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-6  f-sr">
        <h4 class="b-desc"> B </h4>
        <h4 class="b-desc"> A </h4>
        <h4 class="b-desc"> C </h4>
    </div>
```

Comment: @MohammedSwillam well, it works as long as you don't click the button :)

Comment: yeah, I know. I didn't change/alter the code when I created the snippet. if you look at the click handler, the selector is picking up the element with id= `s-alf`, which is not the button. ;)